#  Mysql Queue Start/End time

Tags: mysql, time, queue

I have one problem that I can't resolve.

I have 2 tables.

Table 1:

```
ID | Time
1  | 08:12:54
2  | 08:15:40
3  | 09:30:01
4  | 10:15:15
5  | 10:56:12
6  | 11:00:03
```

Table 2:

```
ID | Name| Previous | Current
1  | Queue | null | 11
2  | Queue | 11 | 19
3  | Queue | 19 | 11
3  | List | null | 11
4  | Queue | 11 | 16
4  | List | null | 11
5  | Queue | null | 15
6  | Queue | 15 | 19
```

The result wanted:

```
NumberQueue | Start | End
11 | 08:12:54 | 08:15:40
19 | 08:15:40 | 09:30:01
11 | 09:30:01 | 10:15:15
15 | 10:56:12 | 11:00:03
...
...
```

The previous and the current fields, have the number of the Queue and I want to know for each Queue, the start date and the end date, knowing that the previous has the previous Queue, and the current has the new Queue.

I want one query that can present this result. Help me. :(

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This select statement should provide the information you need:

```
SELECT Current AS Number, t1out.Time AS Start, (
    SELECT Time FROM Table1 AS t1in
    WHERE t1in.ID > t1out.ID
    ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1
) AS End FROM Table2
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS t1out USING (ID)
WHERE Table2.Name = 'Queue';
```

Comment: Give your example data, this query returns your desired result, as far as my understanding of your DB schema and data set requirements goes.

Comment: I understand this querie, however, going to join lists and i just want the queues.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment, but I see you decided to unaccept my previous answer. So good luck with trying to figure your issue yourself.

Comment: Unaccept? Sorry but i'm new here, and i dont understand too much.
Basically, this querie, dont present the result what i want. Sorry if i give negative feedback to you.

Comment: With your test data, the query gives exactly the result you've described. If it doesn't, you should explain how it should be different.

Comment: I edited the answer, and put more data tables to better understand. Through this query doesnt show the result intended. I think the problem is here "    SELECT Time FROM Table1 AS t1in
    WHERE t1in.ID > t1out.ID
    ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1
"

Comment: My previous queue still shows all the rows from your desired result with your new data, except that it shows one additional row — `(16, '10:15:15', '10:56:12')`. I still do not understand your requirements from your explanation, and do not understand how the result produced by my query differs from the result you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1outer.ID, t1outer.Time AS start, (
    SELECT Time FROM Table1 AS t1inner
    WHERE t1inner.ID > t1outer.ID
    ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1
) AS end, Table2.Previous, Table2.Current
FROM Table1 AS t1outer
LEFT JOIN Table2 USING (ID);
```

Comment: I dont think it was desired because the number of the Current and Previous Queue's aren't ID's in table1.

Only match between Table1.ID and Table2.ID.

Comment: Thanks to resolve my problem. However, i dont specified in the problem that the the queue have a name and through this query its joining all the queues, so dont checking the name of the queue that i want.
Sorry for this inconvenience

Comment: @sh0rt6r - it might be a good idea to accept the answer, as it answers the question. You could try adding the change that you need, or append an edit to the original question, and lanzz may be able to assist within the same question. But it is always a good idea to give things a go oneself first - it's how we learn :)

Comment: Sorry but i'm new in this website. ;) 
I already edit the question. I tried to make my changes but could not. However, i asked for help again who made this query.

Comment: You haven't made any updates to your question, and I see no other question asked by you. I'm going to need more details about your database schema, I have no idea how your queues are named, which of the two tables is holding the queues, what exactly you need selected from the data?

Comment: Sorry for the delay... 
In the table1 i have only the time.
In the table2, the field ID isnt PK because have repeated numbers.
As i have, for example, two queue's woth the same ID's, i just want to know the time for the Queue1.
Through the query that gave me, join with Queue2 also, and i want only for Queue1.

Note: The current and previous are numbers of the queues, and the QueueName are type of queue to differentiate.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I did not understand anything.

Comment: I edited thee question. To understand better, now i have Queue's and List's. And just what i want is the start/end for each number of queue. Lists are to ignore.